# Require users to uninstall previous Android app version on update

Tags: android, google-play

My client has an app that is released on Google Play and we are in the process of releasing an update. Much has changed in the app and due to previous developers not maintaining the code we are forced to do a clean install to get the app to work (without spending countless hours tracking down changes and writing migration scripts).

Is there a way to force users to uninstall-reinstall (or automatically uninstall-reinstall) the app on an update?

Comment: Does your app use the same package name and signing key as the last version of the app? In that case the reinstall is managed by the OS

Comment: Do you want to remove all the user data?

Comment: Just delete all the user data, databases, clear shared preferences, etc.

Comment: More specifically we are using Active Android for ORM and there have been many changes to the Models in the application. I understand that there is a way to update the tables via a migration script, however, the changes have been so many and poorly documented so I would be spending a very long time tracking down all of the changes.

Comment: And yes- we are using the same package name and signing key. Unfortunately this means the database is out of sync and the app crashes on startup. That is why we need to do a clean install.

Comment: Take a look at `onUpgrade()` method of `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.

Comment: as @Daniel mentioned, the package and signing key should be the same. If not changed, all other changes are irrelevant. And as @Grender said `onUpgrade()` method can take any SQL statement you need. You can even run migrations to remove all database records, tables..etc and put new ones.

Comment: you can use the broadcast receiver for self package updated since it will be called only once & write your own logic to clear the data of the application. From api 19 you can directly access the api to clear the application data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do exactly what you asked for. But, if there are only database changes, you can just rename the database file to make your application to start using a new database file and ignore the old one.

**Example:**

```
// in your DatabaseHelper constructor
private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
  super(context, "new_database.db", null, DB_VERSION);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you almost only want to get rid of your stored data. Besides just deleting all the files you have in your package data directories, you could also only clear the data you don't want to have anymore.

```
if (shouldClearData()) {
    for (String name: databaseList())
         deleteDatabase(name);
    for (String name: PREFERENCE_FILES)
        getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().apply();
}
```

Comment: For what I was trying to accomplish this worked well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all user data from your application you can use below code.

```
public static void clearApplicationData() {
    File cache = getInstance().getCacheDir();
    File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
    if (appDir.exists()) {
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for (String s : children) {
                deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));

        }
    }
}
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return dir.delete();
}
```

*where `getInstance()` is your `Application` class instance*

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The updated app cannot check for a prior version number because once it is installed the present version will be its own, not the prior one.

Comment: but u can run it only once after user install this app. Which will helps you to  remove all the previous user data.

Comment: OK, I see that you removed the part about checking for a prior version number.  But now you need a way to prevent all user data from being deleted every time the app runs.  Simple enough, though, to just write a variable to non-volatile storage flagging that the data has already been cleared once.

Comment: Yea you can set variable for that purpose for example you can store any shared prefs value after this action performed, and next time you can check for that value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the app is only on Google Play, you can force users to uninstall and reinstall.

Just have a test for the presence of any non-volatile storage variable that will always be present in the old app, and not in your updated app (if freshly installed) in your onResume() method.

If present, put up a non-cancelable dialog that has a button linking to the app's page on the Play store, with directions to press the button, then the Uninstall button on the store page, and then the Install button on that same store page.

This is not to say that forcing a fresh install is a good idea; it is just an answer to the question as posted.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to wipe all data stored in database, you can increase the database version number. Android will automatically wipe all data from the previous version. But I really don't recommend that because you will remove all user data related to your application and this could cause very angry users which won't use your new application.